# Shadowrun: Hong Kong - Most used/useful etiquette

Tags: shadowrun-hong-kong

In Shadowrun-Returns, there are many etiquette that will allow you to answer or to say something during the dialogue that can save your life, give extra XP or easily solve some puzzles.

Sometimes, a specific etiquette is not even present in the entire story, so it is a waste of Karma points. Other etiquette are constantly showing up.

**Does anyone know what etiquette is the most useful for the Hong Kong release of the Shadowrun-Returns?**

Spoilers:

> So far, Academic and Shadowrunner already appeared 2 times each and I  just started working for Kindly Cheng.

Comment: This was flagged opinion-based, but I disagree. The question defines "most used/useful" as giving most alternative dialogue options and extra XP.

Comment: This question could easily be restructured as "how many times does each etiquette show up".

Comment: Hey @Toast, I'm not looking for a ranking on "how many times each etiquette show up". For instance, the 2 times Academic showed up, they were extremely useless to the plot, just to make the character look "smart". It did not help to solve the case or added anything. On the other hand, the 2 times the Shadowrunner etiquette was available, it clearly could steer the conversation on another direction.

Comment: So you need a list of when each etiquette is used in the game AND the outcome of having that etiquette?

Comment: That would make for an excellent answer. But look, for example, at [Nythain's answer about the base game etiquettes on the Shadowrun Returns forums](http://www.shadowrun.com/forums/discussion/30585/best-etiquettes) (which I guess in turn came from gamefaqs). That format and level of detail would make for a good answer here.

Comment: @Toast , the list of etiquette that has more good outcomes would be great, but a list of etiquette + the outcome would be perfect. On a play-thru, I think it would be fair to have just a list of the most useful etiquette(s). But when I replay the game, I would sure take a note of the etiquette + the outcomes. I don't have level enough to make a Wiki, but I think it would be a good place to write it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Top Tips for Skills requirement in Shadowrun: Hong Kong](http://www.gamepur.com/guide/20034-top-tips-skills-requirement-shadowrun-hong-kong.html#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=55dc1269297d4d2a&at_ab=per-14&at_pos=0&at_tot=1) has all of them I think, but is full of spoilers.

Shadowrunner seems most useful, followed shortly by Gang. Academic comes up very frequently, providing additional information and some better conversation options. Socialite, Security, and Corporate are infrequent and can be worked around. Street never shows up as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'm about to finish the game and I would say that **shadowrunner** is actually the most useful. **Security, Sociality and Corporate** are also extremely useful in some parts of the game to avoid gunfight or gather extra info. And as mentioned in the response, Academic pops up a LOT, but mainly for story enrichment. Gang does not appear that much and sociality can be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Gang, Shadowrunner, Academic and Security

I'm basing this information on

http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=503910261
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=503343380